# What is socket hijacking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, http, rack

I'm reading a great [post](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable) on Rails 5 actioncable introduction. There it says: "Action Cable uses the Rack socket hijacking API to take over control of connections from the application server. ". What does the "socket hijacking" mean?

Comment: if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps! ..However I don't understand why someone gave a negative vote for this question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket Hijacking was implemented with `rack 1.5.0` - a modular Ruby webserver interface.

`Rack 1.5.0` basically provides a simple and adaptable interface for developing apps in rails. It does this by wrapping HTTP requests and their responses in a simply way. It also combines the API's for web servers, web frameworks, and middleware into a single method call.

So, in `rack 1.5.0` socket hijacking is used to allow rails apps to overtake the client socket and perform other operations on it. These operations include:

- Implementing [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
- Streaming data
- Other interactivity between user's browser and server

---

**WebSockets** allows the user to send messages to a server and receive event driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

This is shown in this diagram - as you can see, once the WebSocket connection is opened, messages can be sent and received between the user and server.

[image: WebSockets]

---

Anyway, in the *Rack Socket Hijacking API* that you specified, it essentially provides two modes:

- **Full hijacking API**

  - This gives the app complete control over what goes over the socket. The app server doesn’t send anything over the socket, and lets the app take care of it.
- **Partial hijacking API**

  - This gives the app control over the socket after the app server has already sent out headers. This mode is basically used for streaming.

So - In the end, socket hijacking basically allows ruby/rails apps to override/overtake a client socket and carry out different functions on it, or as you wrote - take control of connections from the application server.